# Z-index for image and div

Tags: html, css, image, z-index

I am looking for a way to allow an image inside of a div to stay overflow:visible and to allow the border of the parent div to overlap the image. Right now I have the image right where I want it using negative margins, but the images is covering the parent div's border.

I tried using z-index for the image and the div but that did now work.

This is the effect that I am trying to achieve.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMHmI.jpg

This where I currently am.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzYA2.jpg

https://jsfiddle.net/zgwywq0v/

```
random html <p>
```

Comment: Put your code in a jsfiddle or codepen so its easier to help! :)

Comment: Sorry, didnt really think that the code would help much. https://jsfiddle.net/zgwywq0v/

Comment: Can you upload the image you are using? In the jsfiddle it's not shown and it would help.

Comment: Added. Its not showing perfectly.

Comment: You havent done much styling yet. You have lot of work to do. You are posting here code that is definitely not in the state as second image suggest. You have even solution in your question title but not in your code. Anyway look at my answer and you should be able to finish it.

Answer (score 1):

Position the image absolutely or relatively and set it `z-index: -1`.

```
div.keynote {
  border: 3px solid #F68B1F;
  position: relative;
}

div.keynote img {
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  top: -20px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zgwywq0v/3/

Answer (score 1):

The main trick here is to use the pseudo element `::before` for the border, and to align them left/right I gave their parent `keynote` `display: flex`

*Note, an obvious way would be using `z-index`, though if one can do it without, do it without*

```css
div.keynote {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}
div.keynote::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid #F68B1F;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
}
div.keynote .speaker-info {
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px 30px 30px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="keynote keynote-border">

  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/240x320">
  </div>

  <div class="speaker-info">
    <p class="name"><a href="#" onclick="alert('Clickable link');">PASTOR</a>
      <br><strong>PATRICK</strong>WINFIELD</p>
    <p class="session">PREPARING FOR TOMORROW</p>
    <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut molestie rutrum ipsum, luctus interdum metus egestas non. Aliquam at mi sollicitudin leo blandit ornare. Suspendisse laoreet ultrices ante. Nunc a velit elementum, pretium erat ut, vulputate
      ante. Maecenas ac magna augue. Donec ac mauris lectus.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

*Updated based on comment*

If you can't/don't want to use `flex`, here is a fallback

```css
div.keynote {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;                /*  clear float and grow with its content  */
}
div.keynote::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid #F68B1F;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
}
div.keynote div:first-child {  
  float: left;
  width: 240px;
}
div.keynote .speaker-info {  
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 240px;             /*  left div width  */
  padding: 30px 30px 30px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="keynote keynote-border">

  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/240x320">
  </div>

  <div class="speaker-info">
    <p class="name"><a href="#" onclick="alert('Clickable link');">PASTOR</a>
      <br><strong>PATRICK</strong>WINFIELD</p>
    <p class="session">PREPARING FOR TOMORROW</p>
    <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut molestie rutrum ipsum, luctus interdum metus egestas non. Aliquam at mi sollicitudin leo blandit ornare. Suspendisse laoreet ultrices ante. Nunc a velit elementum, pretium erat ut, vulputate
      ante. Maecenas ac magna augue. Donec ac mauris lectus.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't keep aspect ratio of the image and the OP seems like quite new to CSS and flex could be hard for him to understand.

Comment: @actimel Thanks, added a wrapper for the image. `flex`, when used like this, is very simple and just line up its children

Comment: Your :after element overlays the content. The content should have z-index or the :after element should have set pointer-events: none (which doesn't work in older browser). I also don't understand why using flexbox for such an easy thing which is doable using float. Unless you don't care abou compatibility. But it is quite clean solution.

Comment: @actimel Thanks for your comment. You should not use `z-index` if not needed, and it is not needed here, and any link beneath will still be clickable so no need for `pointer-events` either. `flex` is not needed, it is just the simplest and best way, in this case, and with +95% support in all major browsers (2 versions back) I don't understand you saying _don't care about compatibility_

Comment: No it won't be clickable. Try it. Flex is IE 10/11+ and you are lucky if you don't have to care about fallbacking. Also older vesions of android browsers have problems with it. I work with it also. Here of course it doesn't matter.

Comment: @actimel Thanks ... `z-index`/`pointer-events` is still not needed, but I made a small mistake, now fixed where I changed to `::before` and added `position: relative;` to the `div.keynote .speaker-info` rule

Comment: @actimel Added a fallback solution for those who can't/don't want to use `flex`

Comment: @rthames62 this seems to me like the best and very flexible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Take the image out of the `div` and place bordered `div` and `img` inside a parent with `position: relative;` then you can change the `position` and `z-index` of bordered `div` and `img` to get your result.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the perfect opportunity to deploy an `::after` pseudo-element - this will enable you to make the orange border exactly the dimensions you need it to be and position it exactly where you want it to be, completely independently of all the other elements.

```css
.profile-card {
margin: 100px 0 0 100px;
width: 600px;
height: 300px;
font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.profile-card::after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
top: 70px;
left: 70px;
z-index: 0;
display: block;
width: 600px;
height: 220px;
border: 3px solid rgb(255,165,0);
}

.profile-card h2 {
font-weight: 300;
}

.profile-card h2 b {
font-weight: 900;
}

.profile-card p,
.profile-card a.more {
font-size: 11px;
}

.profile-card h2,
.profile-card h2 ~ strong,
.profile-card a.more {
text-transform: uppercase;
}

.profile-card img {
display: block;
float: right;
width: 280px;
height: 280px;
background-color: rgb(191,191,191);
border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
transform: translateY(-108px);
}

.profile-card a.more {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
z-index: 6;
margin-left: 90px;
padding: 12px;
color: rgb(255,255,255);
background-color: rgb(255,165,0);
text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-card">
<h2><b>Profile</b> Name</h2>
<img src="/profile-name.png" alt="Profile Photo" />
<strong>Profile Tagline Here</strong>
<p>Paragraph here, paragraph here, paragraph here, paragraph here, paragraph here, paragraph here, paragraph here, paragraph here, paragraph here, paragraph here, paragraph here, paragraph here, paragraph here, paragraph here, paragraph here, paragraph here, paragraph here, paragraph here.</p>
<a class="more" href="/more.html">Read More</a>
</div>
```